# My self referential Sequelize model isn't creating an extra column

Tags: sequelize.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      lastLogin: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    }, {
      paranoid: true,
      classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
          User.hasOne(models.User, {
            as: "createdByUser"
          })

          User.hasOne(models.User, {
            as: "updatedByUser"
          })
        }
      }
    }
  )

  return User
};
```

I would expect a field to be called `createdByUser` in the Postgres DB, but it's not there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      lastLogin: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
      }
    }, {
      paranoid: true
    }
  )

  User.associate = models => {
    User.hasOne(models.User, {
      as: "createdByUser"
    })

    User.hasOne(models.User, {
      as: "updatedByUser"
    })
  }

  return User
};
```

In the new version of Sequelize (4+), there's no need for `classMethods`